# How to initialize an Objective-C struct in constructor?

Tags: objective-c, struct, constructor, initialization

I´m using a struct on Objective-C to store some data, something like this:

```
@interface Interface : NSObject
{
    // my Data
    struct Data
    {
        __unsafe_unretained BOOL isInit;
        __unsafe_unretained BOOL isRegister;
        __unsafe_unretained NSString* myValue;
        
       // Data() : isInit(false), isRegister(false), myValue(@"mYv4lue") {} // Constructor doesnt work
    };

    struct Data myData;  // Create Struct
}
```

But I can't compile with a constructor. I want the values take some default value when I create the struct.

How can I do this?

Comment: I´m cautious, i need the values correctly init when launch some actions and i don ´t want malfunctions

Comment: Is there any reason that this struct can't be converted to a simple class?

Comment: `__unsafe_unretained` isn't applicable to `BOOL`s -- they are primitives, not objects.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Structs don't have initializers, if you want to create a struct with a particular set of values you could write a function that returns creates and initialises it for you:

For example

```
struct Data {
        BOOL isInit;
        BOOL isRegister;
        NSString* myValue;
};

Data MakeInitialData () {
    data Data;
    data.isInit = NO;
    data.isRegister = NO;
    data.myValue = @"mYv4lue";

    return data;
}
```

now you can get a correctly set up struct with:

```
Data newData = MakeInitialData();
```

A note, though; you seem to be using ARC, which doesn't work well with structs that have object pointers in them. The recommendation in this case is to just use a class instead of a struct.

Comment: You might want to mention that this code is Swift, not Objective-c. As it stands, the example won't give you 'data' as a local variable in Objective-c. Pritesh Kadam's answer is much more elegant and comprehensive.

Comment: To be fair, it is Objective-C, as Swift wasn't around in 2012, or 2014. And this wouldn't even compile in Swift as `Data` is a type defined in Foundation.

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's true that I was guessing when I said the code was Swift and as for Pritesh Kadam's answer: I don't what I was thinking and I vow to amend my Swift-calling ways. I am however very sure that this code is not valid Objective-C. And Abizern: "Data is a type defined in Foundation"? Which Foundation? Not NextStep's.

Comment: @ElisevanLooij `Data` is a value type that bridges to `NSData` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data

Comment: Right. See, that's the point: if you'll look at the top of the page of that link, you'll see "Language:Swift". It's not a dropdown, allowing one the option of Objective-C, it's tied to Swift. So, in my Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b) installation where Swift is never used, Data is an unknown type that causes a compiler error "Unknown type name 'Data'".

Answer (score 8):

You could initialize a struct as follows using static object for default settings.

```
typedef struct
{
    BOOL isInit;
    BOOL isRegister;
    __unsafe_unretained NSString* myValue;

} Data;
static Data dataInit = { .isInit = NO, .isRegister = NO, .myValue = @"mYv4lue"};

Data myCopyOfDataInitialized = dataInit;
```

Answer (score 3):

The space where you're doing this -- between curly braces at the beginning of the class's `@interface` block -- doesn't allow running code. It is solely for declarations of ivars. You really shouldn't even be declaring `struct`s in there (I'm surprised that compiles).

Move the constructor call to your class's `init` method. That's where initialization of ivars is supposed to happen in ObjC.

Comment: Setting ivar's is better done in initialize, since initialize is guaranteed to be called only once in an object's lifetime.

Comment: Are you talking about `+initialize`, the _class_ method, @ElisevanLooij? That's called once per _class_, not per _instance. Further, you don't have access to instance variables inside it, because there's no instance of the class.

Comment: `-init`'s return type is either `id` or `instancetype`, not `void`.

Comment: Nice ninja edit. :/ ...and using `init` is what I recommend in my second paragraph. So what are we talking about?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this way:

```
@interface Interface : NSObject
{

   typedef struct tagData

    {
        __unsafe_unretained BOOL isInit;
        __unsafe_unretained BOOL isRegister;
        __unsafe_unretained NSString* myValue;

        tagData(){
           isInit = NO;
           isRegister = NO;
           myValue = NULL;
        }
    } myData;

}
```

Comment: This code will not even compile in Objective-C, unfortunately.