# Binary Search Tree/Search function incompatible pointer type? In C

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to get a simple search function for my Binary Search Tree working but it gives me warnings about incompatible pointer types. If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong or leave a suggestion, that would be much appreciated:

```
bst_node* find_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone){

if(bst->root == NULL || phone == bst->root->phone)
    return bst->root;

if(phone < bst->root->phone)
    return find_node(bst->root->left, phone);

else
    return find_node(bst->root->right, phone);
}
```

Here are the typedefs and structs:

```
typedef struct bst_node bst_node;
typedef struct bstree  bstree;

    struct bst_node
{
    bst_node* left;
    bst_node* right;
    bst_node* parent;
    unsigned long phone;
    char *name;
};

struct bstree
{
    struct bst_node* root;
    int count;
};
```

The error messages:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘find_node’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  return find_node(bst->root->left, phone);

note: expected ‘bstree * {aka struct bstree *}’ but argument is of type ‘bst_node ** {aka struct bst_node **}’
 bst_node* find_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone) {
```

The same error appears for the 'else' function

Comment: Your `left` is of type `bst_node*` but your function `find_node` expects a argument of type `bstree*`

Comment: @Karthick Oh I see. Thank you. But is there a way to get it to work with the left and right pointers? Or do I have to take a different approach?

Comment: Why not have `find_node` accept a `bst_node *` as its first argument and just pass the root of the tree (`bstree->root`) instead of the pointer to the whole `bstree` structure? `find_node` doesn't need the count.

Comment: @lurker I realized the same thing but this is an assignment and we were told not to edit the structs...

Comment: You don't have to edit the struct. Just pass the `root` element of the struct to your `find_node` function and have `find_node` use `bst_node *` instead of `bstree *` as I mentioned.

Comment: @lurker I would really like to but the search function is just one part of the whole assignment. The `main` function uses the search function with `bstree *` but we are not allowed to edit the `main` either... That's why there is really only a limited option available.

Comment: What does the `count` member of `bstree` denote ?

Comment: @tkhurana96 It appears in  `int main` as `bst.count = 0;` but it's not used elsewhere. I probably need to make use of it in one of the other functions of the assignment. It shouldn't be needed for the search function, however.

Comment: Well, you can make an object `bstree left_subtree` in the if part, initialize it with `bst->root->left` as `root` and `0` for `count` and pass it's address, using `&`, to the recursive call. Similar thing can be done for the else part by creating `right_subtree` object

Comment: Initializing `count` to `0` when creating left and right sub tree objects is not semantically right, because that count might be denoting number of nodes in the tree

Comment: If you're that constrained (you have to have those two different structures for the tree root versus the subtrees, you're not allowed to change the structures, and your `find_node` must accept a `bstree *` pointer) then you'll have your `find_node`, which accepts a `bstree *` call a separate recursive function for the subtrees (*e.g.*, `find_node_subtree`). Your `find_node` would just call `find_node_subtree` on the `bstree->root`. Now if you say that's not allowed, then you're probably not understanding your assignment because you'd have a very impractical situation.

Comment: @tkhurana96 Followed your suggestion but something about an invalid initializer

Comment: @Oliver it would be great if you could elaborate on that error and post the code that produced that error

Comment: @tkhurana96 See the answer below

Comment: @Oliver try `bstree subtree_left {bst->root->left, 0};` instead of `bstree subtree_left = bst->root->left;`

Comment: @tkhurana96 Using the `{}` suggestion only throws out syntax errors

Comment: @Oliver try `bstree subtree_left ={bst->root->left, 0};` instead of `bstree subtree_left = bst->root->left;`

Comment: Or simply do this @Oliver try `bstree subtree_left; subtree_left = bst->root->left; subtree_left = 0;`

Comment: @tkhurana96 The second try worked. Thank you! But what does it mean to write `{}` instead of the `bst->root->left`method?

Comment: @Oliver my C is rusty, I was trying a syntax like mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39625151

Comment: @Oliver It's a way of initializing struct object

Comment: And @Oliver, do one thing, update your answer to the correct solution

Comment: @tkhurana96 Well, learned something new today. Thank you for your help!
I will update the answer

Comment: @Oliver, glad I could help, but don&#39;t forget to update your answer  with the solution that worked, and also as I mentioned before, this solution is not semantically right (initializing count to 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem above.
Credits to tkhurana96

```
bst_node* find_node(bstree* bst, unsigned long phone){

if(bst->root == NULL || phone == bst->root->phone)
    return bst->root;

if(phone < bst->root->phone)
    bstree subtree_left = {bst->root->left, 0};
    return find_node(&subtree_left, phone);

else
    bstree subtree_right = {bst->root->right, 0};
    return find_node(&subtree_right, phone);
}
```